# Execute a method when an instance variable is referenced in a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop, class, lazy-initialization

Is it possible to run a function when referring to a variable in a php class rather than simply returning its value, similar to javascript's ability for a variable to hold a method?

```
class LazyClassTest()
{

    protected $_lazyInitializedVar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        /* // How can this call and return runWhenReferrenced() when
           // someone refers to it outside of the class:
           $class = new LazyClass();
           $class->lazy;
           // Such that $class->lazy calls $this->runWhenReferrenced each
           // time it is referred to via $class->lazy?
         */
        $this->lazy = $this->runWhenReferrenced();
    }

    protected function runWhenReferrenced()
    {
        if (!$this->_lazyInitializedVar) {
            $this->_lazyInitializedVar = 'someValue';
        }

        return $this->_lazyInitializedVar
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like PHP5.3: lambda / closures / anonymous functions

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php:

```
<?php
$greet = function($name) {
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP5s magic method `__get($key)` and `__set($key, $value)` might be what you need. More information about them is available in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

Comment: Hmmm... not all of us understand German, so why not share the English manual? :-)

Comment: While this is not what I was looking for, I actually ended up using it and it helped, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably heading in the wrong direction. You normally want to define a getter `getLazyVar()`. There is a reason why people always make properties protected and defined getters / setters: So they can pre- or postprocess the values.

Comment: I agree that it's good practice to use the getLazyVar() practice but my reason for wanting a variable is to keep the class's pattern consistent with other similarly patterned classes that I have so that a method's properties will always be accessible in the exact same way.